# Clean URLs are not working in WampServer 3.1.3. How do I fix it?

Tags: wampserver

This is uncommented in the httpd.conf file.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

When I add this to the httpd.conf file wampserver wont start: `AccessFileName .htaccess`

How do I enable Clean URLs in WampServer 3.1.3? This is for Drupal 8.